# discord.js reaction check not working v14.7.1

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i have this code, when i write the command !classes i get the embed and the 2 reactions but when i check a reaction nothing i happening i dont know whats wrong i tried lookin everywhere, my reaction isnt even getting cancled. im using replit and discord.js version 14.7.1 please help me.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ]
});



client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  // Check if the message starts with the command prefix
  if (message.content.startsWith('!classes')) {
    // Create the embed
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('Classes')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Class 1', value: 'Description of Class 1' },
        { name: 'Class 2', value: 'Description of Class 2' }
      );

    // Send the embed to the same channel
    message.channel.send({ content: 'Here are the available classes:', embeds: [embed] }).then
      (async sentMessage => {
        // Add reactions to the message
        await sentMessage.react('');
        await sentMessage.react('');

        // Wait for a reaction to be added
        const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        
        const collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 });
        const reaction = collected.first();

        try {
          // Check which class was selected
          if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            // Class 1 was selected
            // Send a message asking for homework and due date
            message.channel.send('Please enter your homework for Class 1:');

            // Wait for a response
            const homeworkFilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            const homeworkMessage = await message.channel.awaitMessages(homeworkFilter, { max: 1 });
            const homework = homeworkMessage.first().content;

            message.channel.send('Please enter the due date for your homework (e.g. "Tomorrow at 3pm"):');

            // Wait for a response
            const dateFilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            const dateMessage = await message.channel.awaitMessages(dateFilter, { max: 1 });
            const dueDate = dateMessage.first().content;

            // Send the homework and due date to a different channel
            const homeworkChannel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
            homeworkChannel.send(`Homework for Class 1: ${homework}\nDue date: ${dueDate}`);
          } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            // Class 2 was selected
            // Send a message asking for homework and due date
            message.channel.send('Please enter your homework for Class 2:');

            // Wait for a response
            const homeworkFilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            const homeworkMessage = await message.channel.awaitMessages(homeworkFilter, { max: 1 });
            const homework = homeworkMessage.first().content;

            message.channel.send('Please enter the due date for your homework (e.g. "Tomorrow at 3pm"):');

            // Wait for a response
            const dateFilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            const dateMessage = await message.channel.awaitMessages(dateFilter, { max: 1 });
            const dueDate = dateMessage.first().content;

            // Send the homework and due date to a different channel
            const homeworkChannel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
            homeworkChannel.send(`Homework for Class 2: ${homework}\nDue date: ${dueDate}`);
          } else {
            // Invalid reaction was added
            message.channel.send('Invalid reaction added. Please try again.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
      )
  }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

i tried looking for an answer but nothing helps

Comment: add console.log(reaction.emoji.name) in your event listener

Comment: how will it help? + its not saying anything in the console

Comment: then the issue comes from your filter (I guess that the emoji name is not in the right format)